# Is there an equivalent for html_encode in freemarker?

Tags: security, freemarker

I'd like to prevent potential issues with xss in my freemarker templates. Is there an filter that can be run in the template code that can sanitize the parameters the template receives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type=text name=user value="${user?html}">
```

See documentation [here](http://fmpp.sourceforge.net/freemarker/ref_builtins_string.html).

Comment: According to the docs, this is what I was looking for, it just didn't work the way I expected. I'll have to look into the docs further. Thanks for the tip.